# Flag History - Link

Tags: support, status-bydesign, flagging

I know this may sound stupid, but I can't find the helpful flags link on my user page. Is there any particular reason why this is the case?

On SO, I can find it under profile views, but right now, I cannot find it on this site. I marked this as a bug albeit it might be feature-bydesign as I haven't flagged anything prior to the last two days and maybe it only shows up if you have atleast 1 helpful flag.

Comment: The link will always be shown with the upcoming redesign of the profile page even if one has 0 helpful flags, it looks like. The preview of the redesign is live on Meta.SE.

Comment: Ah, good idea! Consistency is key!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link only exists once you have at least one helpful flag.

The page exists it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/[YourUserID]